# F# How to Percentile Rank An Array of Doubles?

Tags: f#

I am trying to take a numeric array in F#, and rank all the elements so that ties get the same rank.  Basically I'm trying to replicate the algorithm I have below in C#, but just for an array of doubles.  Help?

rankMatchNum = 0;
            rankMatchSum = 0;
            previousScore = -999999999;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < factorStocks.Count; i++)
        {
            //The 1st time through it won't ever match the previous score...
            if (factorStocks[i].factors[factorName + "_R"] == previousScore)
            {
                rankMatchNum = rankMatchNum + 1;     //The count of matching ranks
                rankMatchSum = rankMatchSum + i + 1; //The rank itself...
                for (int j = 0; j <= rankMatchNum; j++)
                {
                    factorStocks[i - j].factors[factorName + "_WR"] = rankMatchSum / (rankMatchNum + 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rankMatchNum = 0;
                rankMatchSum = i + 1;
                previousScore = factorStocks[i].factors[factorName + "_R"];
                factorStocks[i].factors[factorName + "_WR"] = i + 1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I would do it, although this isn't a direct translation of your code.  I've done things in a functional style, piping results from one transformation to another.

```
let rank seq =
  seq
  |> Seq.countBy (fun x -> x)     // count repeated numbers
  |> Seq.sortBy (fun (k,v) -> k)  // order by key
  |> Seq.fold (fun (r,l) (_,n) -> // accumulate the number of items seen and the list of grouped average ranks
      let r'' = r + n             // get the rank after this group is processed
      let avg = List.averageBy float [r+1 .. r''] // average ranks for this group
      r'', ([for _ in 1 .. n -> avg]) :: l)       // add a list with avg repeated
      (0,[])                          // seed the fold with rank 0 and an empty list 
      |> snd                          // get the final list component, ignoring the component storing the final rank
      |> List.rev                     // reverse the list
      |> List.collect (fun l -> l)    // merge individual lists into final list
```

Or to copy Mehrdad's style:

```
let rank arr =
  let lt item = arr |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x < item) |> Seq.length
  let lte item = arr |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x <= item) |> Seq.length
  let avgR item = [(lt item) + 1 .. (lte item)] |> List.averageBy float
  Seq.map avgR arr
```

Comment: @kvb I hope you don't mind, I reformatted your code to play nice with the syntax highlighter

Comment: @kvb should `(_,g)` be changed to `(_,n)`? The current rank seq function doesn't know what `n` is.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you'll probably find this problem far easier to solve in F# if you rewrite the above in a declarative manner rather than in an imperative manner. Here's my off-the-top-of-my-head approach to rewriting the above declaratively:

First we need a wrapper class to decorate our items with a property carrying the rank.

```
class Ranked<T> {
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public double Rank { get; private set; }
    public Ranked(T value, double rank) {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Rank = rank;
    }
}
```

Here, then, is your algorithm in a declarative manner. Note that `elements` is your input sequence and the resulting sequence is in the same order as `elements`. The delegate `func` is the value that you want to rank `elements` by.

```
static class IEnumerableExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<Ranked<T>> Rank<T, TRank>(
        this IEnumerable<T> elements,
        Func<T, TRank> func
    ) {
        var groups = elements.GroupBy(x => func(x));
        var ranks = groups.OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                          .Aggregate(
                              (IEnumerable<double>)new List<double>(),
                              (x, g) =>
                                  x.Concat(
                                      Enumerable.Repeat(
                                          Enumerable.Range(x.Count() + 1, g.Count()).Sum() / (double)g.Count(),
                                          g.Count()
                                      )
                                  )
                    )
                    .GroupBy(r => r)
                    .Select(r => r.Key)
                    .ToArray();

        var dict = groups.Select((g, i) => new { g.Key, Index = i })
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => ranks[x.Index]);

        foreach (T element in elements) {
            yield return new Ranked<T>(element, dict[func(element)]);
        }        
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class MyClass {
    public double Score { get; private set; }
    public MyClass(double score) { this.Score = score; }
}

List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>() {
    new MyClass(1.414),
    new MyClass(2.718),
    new MyClass(2.718),
    new MyClass(2.718),
    new MyClass(1.414),
    new MyClass(3.141),
    new MyClass(3.141),
    new MyClass(3.141),
    new MyClass(1.618)
};
foreach(var item in list.Rank(x => x.Score)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Score = {0}, Rank = {1}", item.Value.Score, item.Rank);
}
```

Output:

```
Score = 1.414, Rank = 1.5
Score = 2.718, Rank = 3
Score = 2.718, Rank = 3
Score = 2.718, Rank = 3
Score = 1.414, Rank = 1.5
Score = 3.141, Rank = 5
Score = 3.141, Rank = 5
Score = 3.141, Rank = 5
Score = 1.618, Rank = 8
```

Note that I do not require the input sequence to be ordered. The resulting code is simpler if you enforce such a requirement on the input sequence. Note further that we do not mutate the input sequence, nor do we mutate the input items. This makes F# happy.

From here you should be able to rewrite this in F# easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very efficient algorithm (O(n<sup>2</sup>)), but it's quite short and readable:

```
let percentile arr =
   let rank item = ((arr |> Seq.filter (fun i -> i < item) 
                         |> Seq.length |> float) + 1.0) 
                   / float (Array.length arr) * 100.0
   Array.map rank arr
```

You might mess with the expression `fun i -> i < e` (or the + 1.0 expression) to achieve your desired way of ranking results:

```
let arr = [|1.0;2.0;2.0;4.0;3.0;3.0|]
percentile arr |> print_any;;

[|16.66666667; 33.33333333; 33.33333333; 100.0; 66.66666667; 66.66666667|]
```

Comment: That's quite elegant, but doesn't match the behavior of the original C# code.

Comment: @kvb: I didn't mean to clone the C# code. I simply wrote something from scratch to answer what's apparently being asked (question title). Didn't really understand the OP code.

Answer (score 0):

Mehrdad's solution is very nice but a bit slow for my purposes. The initial sorting can be done 1 time. Rather than traversing the lists each time to get the number of items < or <= the target, we can use counters. This is more imperative (could have used a fold):

```
let GetRanks2 ( arr ) =
    let tupleList = arr |> Seq.countBy( fun x -> x ) |> Seq.sortBy( fun (x,count) -> x )
    let map = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,float>()
    let mutable index = 1
    for (item, count) in tupleList do
        let c = count
        let avgRank = 
            let mutable s = 0
            for i = index to index + c - 1 do 
                s <- s + i
            float s / float c
        map.Add( item, avgRank )
        index <- index + c
    //
    map
```